# Java error when starting Eclipse on Win 8

Tags: windows, eclipse, java

When starting Eclipse I get the following error:

[image: error]

Obviously it's trying to use javaw.exe from system32-folder, which it shouldn't I guess. I've set the environment-vars to the following:

**JAVA_HOME** : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"

**Path** : "... ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin"

and I added *-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7...\bin\javaw.exe* to eclipse.ini

Java and JDK are installed. x86-version and x64-version.
Has anybody an idea, how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following:

- I removed the *-vm C:\Program* ... entry from eclipse.ini
- I removed the **JAVA_HOME** variable
- I edited the **Path** as follows:
  I moved the path to javaw.exe to the beginning of the **Path**-variable, because it's using the first javaw.exe it finds and there's one in system32-folder whyever.

Comment: Looks like you carried over an old Eclipse installation which you explicitly had configured for this JDK.  Frequently it is easiest just to download and unzip a new copyl.